# How to scoll Swipeabledrawer MUI in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-swipeable-list

I have a swipeabledrawer in React from MUI, which I am using to show a lengthy content. The title should be visible even when the drawer is closed. I had achieved this in the following way
[MUI SwipeableDrawer](https://mui.com/components/drawers/#swipeable-edge)

Sample is added in stackblitz, [please take a look](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kdrsuu?file=demo.tsx)

I can swipe open and close using the puller above the title. But the entire layout is not scroll-able.

I have tried to set the overflow:'scroll' and 'auto', then the content inside is scrollable not the entire layout. and when i do this the top edge with title sticking out when closed is not working.

How can i solve this. thanks

Comment: I think if you set `overflow` to `scroll` on the `.MuiPaper-root` you might get something close to what you're looking for? I was just messing around in the DOM directly.

Comment: @aardvarkk  on line 79 i had done that. not helping

Comment: @aardvarkk .MuiPaper-root is just for the drawer, right? What i am trying is to scroll the layout with drawer including the top part

Comment: So you just want the title to also scroll? I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish I guess.

Comment: @aardvarkk Something like this, [link](https://snack.expo.dev/@ssaul/expandable-drawer-with-scrollable-content) but when the drawer is closed the top part should be visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scroll didn't work because of the `absolute` position of the parent element of the drawer. To fix it, you should change the position of `StyledBox`  inside `SwipeableDrawer` to `relative`, and set it negative margin:

```
        <StyledBox
          sx={{
            position: 'relative',
            marginTop: `${-drawerBleeding}px`,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 8,
            borderTopRightRadius: 8,
            visibility: 'visible',
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
          }}
        >
```

Then wrap your list inside a separate container with max-height which will determine when scroll will appear:

```
const ListContainer = styled('div')(() => ({
  maxHeight: '300px',
  overflow: 'auto',
}));

...

          <ListContainer>
            {animals.map((animal) => {
              return <div>{animal}</div>;
            })}
          </ListContainer>
```

This way the scroll will work.

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kdrsuu-uzzyyy?file=demo.tsx)

Comment: Yes, This works. thanks. But i was looking for a solution where I will be able to scroll the entire layout instead of just the content in drawer. Now we can view the rest of the content by scrolling inside drawer, but to scroll everything up including the contents outside ListContainer. Hope you get what I mean